# Get range of dates from array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of dates that I'd like to get for certain intervals. I've done what I wanted, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it (with datetime64?) as I sort of went in a roundabout way by using `np.where`.

```
dates = [np.datetime64(x) for x in dates] # dates in for x in dates is a list
dates_arr = np.array(dates)
```

```
['2000-01-01' '2001-01-01' '2002-01-01' '2003-01-01' '2004-01-01']
```

```
years = dates_arr.astype('datetime64[Y]').astype(int) + 1970
result = np.where((years > 2000) & (years < 2004))
dates[result[0][0]:result[0][-1]]
```

Output

```
[numpy.datetime64('2001-01-01'), [numpy.datetime64('2002-01-01'), [numpy.datetime64('2003-01-01')]
```

Answer (score 0):

use good old `np.arange()` with arguments of `np.datetime64` type:

```
np.arange(np.datetime64("2002-01-01"), np.datetime64("2005-01-01"), np.timedelta64(1, 'Y'), dtype='datetime64[Y]').astype('datetime64[D]')


array(['2002-01-01', '2003-01-01', '2004-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```